# Output error with awk and a complex find

Tags: linux, bash, text, awk

I have a data dump from an LDAP database I am trying to extract some key fields.

```
awk '/mail:|uid:|generationQualifier:|initials:|givenName:|fullName:|messageServer:|telephoneNumber:|facsimileTelephoneNumber:/{s=s", "$0} /description:/ {s=s", "$0 "\n" ;} END{printf substr(s,3)}' dump2.txt >> mainDump2.csv
```

I am able to recover all of the data but the output is not adding a \n 'all the time'. For the most part it does but on lines such as:

```
sASLoginSecret:: ngAAgAHkAbwB1vAG0AIABoAGkAZwBoACAAcwBjAGgAbwBvAGwAPwCwAAA
 AabodpVFjlT1Hf8fQRXNPMvaHPPxCFuysBdTMQ9SX+ycAWnCQydlkBP+eo6VrspaTnOxk0rBf
 MMI5x+F+TwogburQi3mphOY8ueffckjBDMgDFN2GlXCmLb1BQIVLFZz2HDUadB7JNl3OpfvRd7i0U
 t4xMQ=
mail: kletcher@land.edu
uid: kfletcher
givenName: Kat
fullName: Kat letcher
Language: English
messageServer: cn=IIS5,ou=LAND,o=landCollege
title: Executive Director of Institutional Advancement
telephoneNumber: 432-555-4519
sn: Fletcher
securityEquals: cn=AllNWUsers-Group,ou=GROUPS,ou=LAND,o=landCollege
securityEquals: cn=MC-FacStaff-Group,ou=GROUPS,ou=LAND,o=landCollege
securityEquals: cn=MC-FullTimers-Group,ou=GROUPS,ou=LAND,o=landCollege
securityEquals: cn=InstAdvFolder-Group,ou=IA,ou=LAND,o=landCollege
passwordUniqueRequired: TRUE
passwordRequired: TRUE
passwordMinimumLength: 8
passwordExpirationTime: 20141130124749Z
passwordExpirationInterval: 15552000
passwordAllowChange: TRUE
ou: Institutional Advancement & MC Foundation
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: Person
objectClass: ndsLoginProperties
objectClass: Top
eMailAddress: 7#kfletcher@land.edu
loginTime: 20140911135740Z
loginMaximumSimultaneous: 2
loginIntruderAddress:: MSMKBwcB
loginGraceRemaining: 6
loginGraceLimit: 6
l: PAD 143
ndsHomeDirectory: cn=NWCL1_FACHOME,ou=LAND,o=landCollege#0#home\kfletche
 r
groupMembership: cn=AllNWUsers-Group,ou=GROUPS,ou=LAND,o=landCollege
```

it outputs like this:

https://bpaste.net/show/cd743ee697d3

thats because some people don't have fax numbers so the string match never occurs and no new line is added. 'But', everybody does have an email address but I am unable to figure out how make it add new line in front of mail: and then print the line.

How would I edit my awk to output such as

```
\n mail: ...
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Again**

You surely aren't using the above code for a 20GB file? However long does it take - you keep appending a line at a time to a single variable and only ever output it at the end - when the one string has presumably reached a good few hundred MB or more...

Why on Earth don't you output each line as soon as it is complete and then start building the next one? Something like this, but a few fiels omitted for clarity:

```
awk '/uid:|givenName:|fullName:|description:/{
        if(length(s)>0)s=s", "            # add comma separator if s already has anything in it
        s=s $0                            # append this line to s
     }
     /^mail:/{
        if(length(s)>0)printf "\n%s",s    # if s has anything in it, output new line and s
        s=$0                              # start building up s afresh with email address
     }
     END{print s}' file
```

**Updated**

No, I mean that if you have a string called `MAIL`, and you want to print a new line before it, you can do this:

```
MAIL="Hello I am some mail";   printf "\n%s",MAIL;
```

**Original Answer**

I think you mean this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "\nstring:%s\nnumber:%d\n","string",42}'

string:string
number:42
```

Comment: You mean like this?  ->  awk '/uid:|generationQualifier:|initials:|givenName:|fullName:|messagerver:|telephoneNumber:/{s=s", "$0} BEGIN{printf "\nmail:%s","string",42} {s=s", "$0 "\n" ;} END{printf substr(s,3)}' dump2.txt >> mainDump3.csv   ->  It did not have the desired effects.

Comment: The file I am searching is 20 gig. I don't see where setting the entire file to a variable is going to do very much good and you are completely ignoring the fact that this is a complex search (6 different items). I have already tried to put BEGIN in various places in my code and nothing works. I don not see where your code could assist. Respectfully. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: I have updated my answer - please have another look.